# Ошибка подключения базы Битрик (bitrix)

Tags: mysql, битрикс, mysqli

Разворачиваю бекап сайта на локалке (опен сервер), в фале settings.php и dbconn.php, прописал верные данные подключения к базе данных,
 кусок с файла dbconn :

```
define("DBPersistent", false);
$DBType = "mysql";

$DBHost = "localhost";
$DBLogin = "root";
$DBPassword = "";
$DBName = "zoo*****";
$DBDebug = false;
$DBDebugToFile = false;
define("MYSQL_TABLE_TYPE", "INNODB");
define("BX_USE_MYSQLI", true);
```

Кусок с файла settings:

```
  'connections' => 
  array (
    'value' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'className' => '\\Bitrix\\Main\\DB\\MysqliConnection',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'zoo****',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'options' => 2,
      ),
    ),
    'readonly' => true,
  ),
);
```

Для отслеживания ошибки значение false в 'debug' => false, поставил на true 'debug' => true.
И получил на сайте следующее

```
[Bitrix\Main\DB\ConnectionException] 
Mysql connect error [localhost]: (1049) Unknown database 'zoomagazine1' (400)
W:\domains\ZooMagazine\bitrix\modules\main\lib\db\mysqliconnection.php:65
#0: Bitrix\Main\DB\MysqliConnection->connectInternal()
    W:\domains\ZooMagazine\bitrix\modules\main\lib\db\mysqliconnection.php:122
#1: Bitrix\Main\DB\MysqliConnection->queryInternal(string, array, NULL)
    W:\domains\ZooMagazine\bitrix\modules\main\lib\db\connection.php:330
#2: Bitrix\Main\DB\Connection->query(string)
    W:\domains\ZooMagazine\bitrix\modules\main\lib\config\option.php:226
#3: Bitrix\Main\Config\Option::load(string, NULL)
    W:\domains\ZooMagazine\bitrix\modules\main\lib\config\option.php:53
#4: Bitrix\Main\Config\Option::get(string, string, string)
    W:\domains\ZooMagazine\bitrix\modules\main\lib\httprequest.php:392
#5: Bitrix\Main\HttpRequest->prepareCookie(array)
    W:\domains\ZooMagazine\bitrix\modules\main\lib\httprequest.php:69
#6: Bitrix\Main\HttpRequest->__construct(object, array, array, array, array)
    W:\domains\ZooMagazine\bitrix\modules\main\lib\httpapplication.php:46
#7: Bitrix\Main\HttpApplication->initializeContext(array)
    W:\domains\ZooMagazine\bitrix\modules\main\lib\application.php:122
#8: Bitrix\Main\Application->initializeExtendedKernel(array)
    W:\domains\ZooMagazine\bitrix\modules\main\include.php:23
#9: require_once(string)
    W:\domains\ZooMagazine\bitrix\modules\main\include\prolog_before.php:14
#10: require_once(string)
    W:\domains\ZooMagazine\bitrix\modules\main\include\prolog.php:10
#11: require_once(string)
    W:\domains\ZooMagazine\bitrix\header.php:1
#12: require(string)
    W:\domains\ZooMagazine\index.php:3
```

Догадываюсь что это связано с mysql - mysqli 
Прошу помощи разобраться. Спасибо!

Comment: Mysql connect error [localhost]: (1049) Unknown database 'zoomagazine1' (400) - Он же вам ясно пишет в ошибке что не видит данной БД - проверьте настройки

Comment: Импорт БД то делали? Может у вас руками была создана БД, но таблиц в ней нет, пока бекап базы не зальёте.

К тому же правильно выше написали, что ошибка указывает на отсутствие самой БД.

На сколько я знаю в OS может MySQL либо вообще не запуститься, либо его можно менять в настройках модулей.

Поменяли версию MySQL == получили чистую БД. (В OS)
Так что советую так же проверить корректно выбранную версию

Answer (score 0):

А как вы разворачиваете?

в ошибке написано, что нет такой БД.

Для "правильного" восстановления бэкапа используйте `restore.php` (вот ссылка http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/scripts/restore.php) от Битрикса и не надо будет в файлах `settings.php` и `dbconn.php` ничего менять